# Script to read file, find in the file system, and move to a directory

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm horrible with scripting and have been pouring over sites for the past 2 days and haven't found a solution, nor been able to piece one together. I'm at my wits end and need some help.

I have a text file with partial names and numbers that I need to find within a directory and its subdirectories and move to a separate directory.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
#!/bin/bash
getArray() {
   array=()
   while IFS= read -r line
   do
        array+=("$line")
   done < "$1"
}

getArray "dan.txt"
for e in "${array[@]}"
do
        mv "$e" /root/moved
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by partial names?

Comment: Tell us the filename and also its full path

Comment: Correction, the text file contains the list of file names, no extensions. Location of the text file is in the /input/files.txt and the location of the data is in the /data/Match directory and subdirectories therein.

Comment: Can you show (some lines of) dan.txt? Filenames without path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by partial file names, you mean they have something that they match within each file name, you can do:

```
find . -name "foo*"
```

If it's dependent also on the directory (i.e., any parent folders that are within the path), use the `-regex` option flag instead, which will match agaisnt the entire file path, instead of the file name:

```
find . -regex '.*/foo/[^/]*.doc'
```

So:

```
while read -r line; do
    find . -name "$line"
done < "$1"
```

**EDIT** per the comments:

```
while read -r line; do
    find "/data/Match" -type f -iname "$line\.*" -exec mv -t /root/moved {} \;
done < "$1"
```

You may need to change the `-iname` argument to the following:

- If they are complete file names (e.g., line with value "filename.txt" matches a file named "filename.txt), then `-iname "$line"`.
- If they are partial file names (e.g., line with value "file" matches "file.txt" and "filename.txt"), then `-iname "$line*"`.
- If they are complete names without file extensions, (e.g., line with value "file" matches "file.txt", but not "filename.txt"), then `-iname "$line\.*"`

Bit of an explanation for that `find` command btw:

- `-type f` - files only (`d` for directories, `l` for soft/hardlinks);
- `-iname` - like `-name`, but case-insensitive;
- `-exec` - command to execute for each matching file, ending with `\;`
- `mv -t /root/moved {}` - the `-t` option is the target directory, followed by the path of that target to move the file to. The source file argument (i.e., the file path we're moving) is the final parameter in `mv`, which is `{}`, which represents the current file path in `find -exec` command.

Note that you may need to play with `"$line*"` as I can't tell how vague your names are from the text file. If they will definitely match from the beginning (e.g., a line in the file with the value "somefile"  *only* matches a file named in the format "somefile.*", where the * is any amount of characters)

Comment: Thanks Nick. I added a correction above. The files to be moved are unique and there are nearly 34k entries.

Comment: @baghdaddy4 Check the update - that'll do you over I think.

Comment: Nick. Thanks for the update and apologies for the vagueness of the naming schemes. I cannot divulge much more other than they are all unique filenames.

I entered the edited portion into the script and receive the following error:
    ./input.txt: line 4: : No such file or directory

It errors on the "done < "$1"" statement. What is that portion of the script referring to?

Comment: I'll update the question slightly to help you choose the correct command. Have you tried it out btw?

Comment: @baghdaddy4 Whew! Final update for you - that should definitely solve your problem. Let me know if that worked.

Comment: Thanks Nick. That worked when I ran the './script.sh files.txt' command. I appreciate the help.